# Animating SVG Inline

Tags: animation, svg

I have this setup working beautifully with SVG but I was curious if anyone knew how to smooth the transition and/or add animation between the hover animations I have. Right now the scale is being increased on hover and if I could get that animated somehow that would be awesome. I imagine inline JS somewhere would be best / most flexible, but i'm not sure exactly how to animate SVG properlly...

http://jsfiddle.net/468gm/

I imagine somewhere inline here would be best, but again im not sure if its possible to smooth the existing scale effect with inline SVG or if a different method would be needed to achieve a animated version of this hover effect

```
importedPaths.setAttribute("transform","translate("+transX+" "+transY+")scale("+scale+" "+scale+")")
```

Comment: Do you want them to get thinner like you have or just get longer? Also, should they be evenly distributed or non-evenly distributed like you have?

Comment: I actually would like them to get longer, not thinner, and an animation ontop of that... if possible. They can be unevenly distributed thats fine... I originally had them evenly distributed but I made them more to look exactly like my design so that part is fine, its just correcting the animation at this point

Comment: You did it in a very interesting way

Comment: I set up the original svg html and got help for the JS part so im a bit limited in editing that part to what I need but the creator said it would require JS to handle animation possibly rather than being able to have the svg do the animation..?

Comment: I would just recommend using CSS transitions but the way that it's set up is making it more difficult... Is there any reason why the number of arrows has to be generated by js instead of coded as SVG elements? As in are there a dynamic number?

Comment: Would a solution that used css3 animation be an option? Example from another question: http://jsfiddle.net/km4u9/2/ perhaps with the `#bubbles .liquid` selector changed to `#bubbles:hover .liquid`?

Comment: definitely css3 would be an option. Although I couldnt find online how to target <use> tags in css and simply doing #myBlackArrow in css wouldnt properly target anything either so im not sure what to target to apply the css transition.

Also there is no reason Zach, its how the guy helped me made it but I think it is to get them in the circle formation unless you think it can be done by svg?

Comment: @mike You can definitely make the entire thing with just SVG and then animate each line individually, it's just up to getting it right and using an SVG type that is selectable. If I have some time later I will try to help, someone may beat me to it though, knowing the SO community

Comment: ok great I'de really appreciate it! The guy helping me said it would be much easier using a different type like polygon but I think it needs to be paths since my objects are very specific with lots of points? What I mean is, im using arrows right now as reference, but my real svg path has a tip with lots of points and is separated from the bottom so I believe it needs to be 2 paths in a group? This is what I get when I output form illustrator anyway. So ya if you can do it with a different type of object then great but with my limited knowledge of SVG I believe it has to be 2 paths...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing around with your code I decided a non-js solution would be the best since you don't have a dynamic number of arrows. [**Check out the rough demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8D8cp/)

I was able to add a CSS `hover` event to the elements by first putting them each in their own group (`<g>`) and applying the `transform` you gave them to that group. Then on `hover` I used `transform: scaleY(1.3);` and `transition:all 0.5s` to make the arrows grow. You also have to have a default `scale(1)` for the paths which I didn't expect, but that's just another couple lines

```
/* CSS */
use:hover { 
    -webkit-transform:scaleY(1.3);
    transform:scaleY(1.3);
}
use {
    -webkit-transform:scaleY(1);
    transform:scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
    transform-origin: bottom center;    
    transition:all 0.5s;
}

/* SVG */
<svg id="mySVG" x="0" y="0" width="900" height="800" overflow="visible">
    <defs id="myDefs">
        <g id="myBlackArrow" fill="#0a8c9e" transform="translate(-421.37805790890565 -409.89077969361676)scale(0.1587493937731687 0.1587493937731687)" filter="url(#f2)" >
            <path d="M2553.826,1137.28l-2.772-1.719l29.799,1445.434l195.02,1.004l9.765-1448.729 c0,0-63.94,42.007-113.36,42.007S2553.826,1137.28,2553.826,1137.28z"></path>
            <path d="M2451.84,1058.265c0,0,171.983,75.005,216.505,75.005s188.535-75.005,188.535-75.005l-190.691-366.037 L2451.84,1058.265z"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="myGrayArrow" fill="#1c9eb0" transform="translate(-421.37805790890565 -409.89077969361676)scale(0.1587493937731687 0.1587493937731687)" filter="url(#f1)">
            <path d="M2553.826,1137.28l-2.772-1.719l29.799,1445.434l195.02,1.004l9.765-1448.729 c0,0-63.94,42.007-113.36,42.007S2553.826,1137.28,2553.826,1137.28z"></path>
            <path d="M2451.84,1058.265c0,0,171.983,75.005,216.505,75.005s188.535-75.005,188.535-75.005l-190.691-366.037 L2451.84,1058.265z"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="myWhiteArrow" fill="#47c9db" transform="translate(-421.37805790890565 -409.89077969361676)scale(0.1587493937731687 0.1587493937731687)">
            <path d="M2553.826,1137.28l-2.772-1.719l29.799,1445.434l195.02,1.004l9.765-1448.729 c0,0-63.94,42.007-113.36,42.007S2553.826,1137.28,2553.826,1137.28z"></path>
            <path d="M2451.84,1058.265c0,0,171.983,75.005,216.505,75.005s188.535-75.005,188.535-75.005l-190.691-366.037 L2451.84,1058.265z"></path>
        </g>
    </defs>
    <defs>
        <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <defs>
        <filter id="f2" x="0" y="0">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15"></feGaussianBlur>
        </filter>
    </defs>

    <g transform="translate(400 400) rotate(    0)"><use xlink:href="#myGrayArrow"></use></g>
    <g transform="translate(400 400) rotate( 22.5)"><use xlink:href="#myGrayArrow"></use></g>
    <g transform="translate(400 400) rotate(   45)"><use xlink:href="#myGrayArrow"></use></g>
    <!-- Found below -->
    <g transform="translate(400 400) rotate(   90)"><use xlink:href="#myGrayArrow"></use></g>
    <g transform="translate(400 400) rotate(112.5)"><use xlink:href="#myGrayArrow"></use></g>
    <g transform="translate(400 400) rotate(  135)"><use xlink:href="#myGrayArrow"></use></g>
    <g transform="translate(400 400) rotate(157.5)"><use xlink:href="#myGrayArrow"></use></g>
    <!-- Found below -->
    <g transform="translate(400 400) rotate(202.5)"><use xlink:href="#myGrayArrow"></use></g>
    <g transform="translate(400 400) rotate(  225)"><use xlink:href="#myGrayArrow"></use></g>
    <g transform="translate(400 400) rotate(247.5)"><use xlink:href="#myGrayArrow"></use></g>
    <g transform="translate(400 400) rotate(  270)"><use xlink:href="#myGrayArrow"></use></g>    
    <!-- Found below -->
    <g transform="translate(400 400) rotate(  315)"><use xlink:href="#myGrayArrow"></use></g>
    <g transform="translate(400 400) rotate(337.5)"><use xlink:href="#myGrayArrow"></use></g>


    <g transform="translate(400 400) rotate( 67.5)"><use xlink:href="#myWhiteArrow"></use></g>
    <g transform="translate(400 400) rotate(  180)"><use xlink:href="#myWhiteArrow"></use></g>
    <g transform="translate(400 400) rotate(292.5)"><use xlink:href="#myWhiteArrow"></use></g>
</svg>
```

The only things you have left to do are to decide which arrows should have `#myBlackArrow` as opposed to `#myGrayArrow` (the way you have it on your demo seems random), fix the alignment of the arrows (the groups are wider than they should be - 75px when they are actually only like 65px so the rotation is off by around 10px), and add the gradient to the background

If you're looking to target the specific types to have separate hover events for each, you can add a `data-` attribute and select it with CSS. I decided to use `data-aColor` to keep it unique and because it's the arrow color. You can then select the data attribute with CSS by using the following: `[data-aColor="gray"] { ...`  [**Here's a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8D8cp/1/) of what I mean

Comment: Thanks a lot this works really well! Its weird you are just using use{} in css and it is targeting...in my example I cant get the css to target the same way, maybe because your using groups around the <use>...anyway Im going to implement this in about an hour and let you know if there are any other issues. One thing I can already think...the canvas size right now is big enough that you dont see it, but on a big screen you can always see the reference groups on the upper left...when I try turning them off it turns them all off...do you know of a way to get rid of the reference  objects?

Comment: It seems to be tricky for me to target anything successfully in svg...how would I apply different animations to each black, gray, white arrow? I cant seem to select them and give them different css with just targeting the id's

Comment: @mike I added how to select each type to differ the transition. I am unsure as to what reference objects you're referencing, I don't see any I'm afraid